# Multithreading error in Ubuntu Virtual Machine?

Tags: ubuntu, c++

I am a beginner in multithreading and I use Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS Virtual Machine from Windows 10. I started multithreading by compiling a very simple hello world file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void call_from_thread()
{
    cout << "Hello Ubuntu" << endl;
}

main()
{
    cout << "Hello Ubuntu from main" << endl;
    pthread t1(call_from_thread);
    t1.join();
}
```

When I try to compile this using the following command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o multithread test2.cpp -pthread
```

it throws the following error:

```
'pthread' was not declared in this scope.
```

In the line `pthread t1(call_from_thread);`
What am I missing here? Does it need any additional libraries to be downloaded?

Comment: What version of ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.02

Comment: C++ threads and pthreads are two different things. You need to decide which one you want to use, and stick to it.

Comment: But... but I created the code from this tutorial: 
    https://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/12/16/cpp-11-thread-tutorial/

If I decide to use pthreads, what more should I do?

Comment: If by "created from" you mean "randomly mixed different incompatible parts of" then yes you have created it. Why do you think it would work? The tutorial shows you how to do C++ threads in the first code example. Just copy it. It also shows you how to do pthreads in the second example. Just copy it. But don't try to combine them. If you want my opinion, use C++ threads, they are much easier.

Comment: If you observe my code and the first fragment of this tutorial, you will realize that they are the same. I haven't gone to the second fragment as the first is not working. And I have included everything the code in the tutorial does, and every command is the same as the tutorial. The only thing that's changing is the "cout" commands. Any idea why it isn't working in my system?

Comment: Oh, as it turns out, the first example (the one I tried to compile) has c++ threads and for some weird reason, it is not working. The second one that uses pthreads is working perfectly. So, I guess it has something to do with compatibility with the Ubuntu 16.04.2

Comment: "they are the same" no they are not. Your code says `pthread t1` and the code in the tutorial says `std::thread t1`. "for some weird reason, it is not working" This is not a valid description of a problem. Post error messages or other manifestations of unwanted behaviour. What version of gcc are you using?

Comment: Oh my god. How didn't I notice this? You're right. Any suggestions from which family should I start? C++ or pthreads? I know their differences. As a beginner, which would be the best? C++ for their simplicity?

Comment: Yes use C++ threads.